# How to prevent a thread from reading to DPDK RX and TX buffers?

Tags: c, dpdk, sgx

I am implementing **dpdk-based** network functions with the aim to deploy them in docker containers.

The containers are connected through ovs-dpdk.

In the network function, I need an **(A) shim layer** that will perform (1) some verifications RX packets before transmitting them to the network function **(B) core logic**, (2) and some verifications for each TX packet before transmitting them to the NIC. **(A) shim layer** is running on *thread 1* and  **(B) core logic** is running on *thread 2*.

**Importantly**, the **(B) core logic** should not be able to directly access the RX buffers because the **(A) shim layer** must first process the incoming packets. In other words, I want to prevent an adversary that compromises the **(B) core logic** code and get the address of RX buffers to thwart this control.

What mechanisms can I set up to achieve that specification?

Below, I provide a high-level architecture of the network function.
[The Network function architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMeBX.png)

Additionaly, this is my system setting {

OS : Ubuntu Server 18.04

Kernel (uname -r) : 5.4.0-77-generic

CPU model name : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7567U CPU @ 3.50GHz

OVS :  2.15.0  (the containers are connected through ovs-dpdk with vhostuser ports).

DPDK : 20.11.1
}

Comment: the question `title` and `real intention` contradicts. I humbly request you properly word the question as a title. This is because your real intention is to have 2 stage processing. Stage-1 is done by thread-A and Stage-2 is done by thread-B. Please update the following information 1) DPDK version 2) OS version 3) Docker version 4) Rte_eal_init arguments passed for sample code 5) sample code snippet to reproduce the bug.

Comment: Okay thank you @VipinVarghese. I will provide your requested details.

Comment: @VipinVarghese I have considered your suggestions. To clarify why I used this title, it is because I want thread 1 to hold exclusive access to the RX buffers.

Comment: thanks for sharing details of the platform. DPDK PMD. The reason for the confusion is you may be asking `what is the best way to allow DPDK mbuf from thread-1 to software enclave SGX which is thread-2`. Or are you asking `I want certain pre-cursor check to be executed first by thread-1 then only function running on thread-2 should process the packets`. Currently from your title it gives the impression you are asking `how can I isolate therad-2 from ever processing RX mbuf processed in thread-1 like software guard or lock to memory location`.  Please make it clear!!

Comment: thank you @VipinVarghese. What I am asking is well expressed in the last question you formulate.

Comment: @VipinVarghese Another detail is that I'm using shared memory to pass packets between DPKD and the 1) Shim layer, 2) and between the Shim layer and the core logic.  I implement this by creating a rings that will contain pointers to packets buffers. This is inspired by two published papers :

Comment: [1] Poddar, R., Lan, C., Popa, R. A., & Ratnasamy, S. (2018). Safebricks: Shielding network functions in the cloud. In 15th {USENIX} Symposium on Networked Systems Design and Implementation ({NSDI} 18) (pp. 201-216).

Comment: [2] Kuvaiskii, D., Chakrabarti, S., & Vij, M. (2018). Snort intrusion detection system with intel software guard extension (intel sgx).

Comment: as mentioned in my first comment there a lot of missing details, Since now you have mentioned you are using `DPDK RING` to send DPDK `MBUF` ring this violates your ideology `How to prevent a thread from reading to DPDK RX and TX buffers?` as you are passing a pointer to mbuf buffer. I humbly request you to please formulate your question with code snippet again.